# Distinct doesn't work on Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

The `.Distinct()` does not work, as you can see it is returning duplicated records (with the same Id)

I also tried:

```
Vendors = c.Item.VendorSpecifications
           .Select(v => new APVendorSimpleView { Id = v.VendorId, Name = v.Vendor.Name, Code = v.Vendor.Code })
           .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
           .Select(x => x.First())
           .ToList(),
```

and it threw an exception

[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]

Comment: What exception did the `GroupBy` code throw?

Comment: `.Distinct()` calls `.Equals()` on the objects in the collection to determine if they are "the same". The class `APVendorSimpleView` probably does not override `Equals()`, so all instances are considered distinct, even if they have the same property values.

Answer (score 3):

Before explaining the Distinct. Your exception feels like a `null ref exception` coming from `v.Vendor.Name` or similar inside your `select APVendorSimpleView`. If Vendor is `null` you cannot access the Name property and you get an exception.

For the `Distinct()` here is what the Docs mention.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8

> If you want to return distinct elements from sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the IEquatable generic interface in the class. The following code example shows how to implement this interface in a custom data type and provide GetHashCode and Equals methods.

Does your `APVendorSimpleView` model meet the above criteria?

```
public class Product : IEquatable<Product>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Product other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return Code.Equals(other.Code) && Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

         //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
         int hashProductName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();

         //Get hash code for the Code field. 
         int hashProductCode = Code.GetHashCode();

         //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
         return hashProductName ^ hashProductCode;
     }
}

//Code example
Product[] products = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                       new Product { Name = "lemon", Code = 12 } };

//Exclude duplicates.

IEnumerable<Product> noduplicates =
    products.Distinct();

foreach (var product in noduplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(product.Name + " " + product.Code);

/*
    This code produces the following output:
    apple 9 
    orange 4
    lemon 12
*/
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it assumes that the OP is comparing elements that are the same on 1 column, but different on others. Is that a fair assumption looking at OP's code?

Comment: Documentation of LINQ to Objects usually doesn't apply for LINQ to Entities (EF) since the later uses different approach (SQL translation). As soon as there is no client evaluation, i.e. EF Core 1.x / 2.x

Comment: @Dennis1679 no it is not a fair assumption. I just provided the same example that Microsoft provides since i am refering them. I am sure the author can modify his code.

Comment: @IvanStoev **fair point**, i am not that familiar. I am not sure the author queries the context immediately there is no proof of that. Nevertheless could you provide more info of what you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
....
Vendors = c.Item?.VendorSpecifications?.GroupBy(x => new 
                                               { 
                                                   Id = x.VendorId, 
                                                   Name = x.Vendor.Name, 
                                                   Code = x.Vendor.Code 
                                               })
                                       .Select(x => new APVendorSimpleView 
                                               { 
                                                   Id = x.Key.Id, 
                                                   Name = x.Key.Name, 
                                                   Code = x.Key.Code 
                                               }), 
....
```